# Всем привет помогите пожайлуста срочно, как в Java сравнить на совпадение символов строк

Tags: java

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String Str = "Java: The best";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Str.length(); i++){
        char x = Str.charAt(i);
        if (x == ":"){
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Чем вызвана срочность?

Comment: Здачей задания в Универ для зачета...

Comment: "Здачей задания в Универ для зачета" - не является уважительной причиной.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (str.indexOf(":") >= 0) {
    System.out.println("есть");
}
```